# When i run the code below in w3c validator it returns this error "End tag a violates nesting rules.". Where might be the problem

Tags: html

```html
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
  <a href="hummer.html">
    <img class="gallery" src="../assets/images/LIMO/HUMMER/HUMMER_1_252_578_90711.png" alt="Long Stretched Hummer"/>
  </a>
  <span>
    <label class="col-lg-12 btn-1"><a href="hummer.html">HUMMER</a></label>
  </span>
</div>
```

when i run the code in browser, just executes perfectly, but in w3c validator it returns an error. where have i gone wrong guys. help me please.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the complete HTML code you have, which you have used in the w3c validator.

Comment: Validates fine if you wrap it in the standard HTML boilerplate. `<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><title>Title</title></head><body> ... </body></html>`